# Query top spring

Tags: mysql, spring

I want to view 4 products on page. but I tried with query:

```
Select * Form table Limit 4
```

but my page has err:

> Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:
>   * near line 1, column 7 [`SELECT*FROM Book Limit 4`]

Comment: you seems to be using hibernate hql not sql if that is the case check the hql syntax. Show the code that running this query.

Comment: yes, I'm using hibernate hql

Comment: Try Query query = session.createQuery("from table");
query.setFirstResult(start);
query.setMaxResults(end);

Comment: SQLQuery sql=session.createSqlQuery("select * from table"); This will work

Comment: I'm trying but not work. My code: public List<Book> gettop4() {
  Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
  String hql = "FROM Book";
  Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  List<Book> list = query.list();
  return list;
 }

Answer (score 0):

When you create the query from HQL

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(the hql here);
```

you can use `query.setMaxResults(4)` method rather than limit